# electron-vite (react) print in portrait not working

Tags: printing, electron, vite, electron-react

I am migrating one of my old react-electron applications to **electron-vite** [doc](https://electron-vite.org/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-electron-vite-project). This application has a pos printer feature which was implemented using **react-to-print**. The printing will be in portrait. When I migrated it to `electron-vite` printing functionality started to act weird. Print always comes in landscape. with very small font size.

old electron version

```json
"electron": "^22.0.0",
```

new electron version

```json
"electron": "^25.6.0",
```

I am not sure if it's a problem with the latest version of **electron** or **electron-vite**. So, I tried to update my printing options and printing functions as well.

print options in both:

```js
const printOptions = {
  silent: true,
  preview: true,
  printBackground: true,
  color: true,
  margin: {
    marginType: 'printableArea'
  },
  landscape: false,
  pagesPerSheet: 1,
  collate: false,
  copies: 1
}
```

printer function(new):

```js
ipcMain.on('toMain', async (event, url) => {
  console.log('print invoked', url)
  const win = new BrowserWindow({ show: false, width: 302, nodeIntegration: true })

  win.loadURL(url)

  win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win.webContents.print(printOptions, (success, failureReason) => {
      console.log('Print Initiated in Main...')
      if (!success) console.log('ERR', failureReason)
    })
  })

  return true
})
```

In the old app I only used `show: false` to create the browser window.
I tried to set the approximate print page size (80mm) to the window as `width:302`. As per the documentation I have set print landscape to false in printer options (even if it is the default).

I am aware of the **electron-pos-printer** library. but it can't be used I have lot of customization to make which is out of its scope

I tried to print a sample blog webpage with `landscape: false` which still gave a landscape output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out that this issue is not related to the migration to electron-vite. Actually, electrons above v22.x.x is having this issue.

What I did was to downgrade the electron dev dependency to `22.0.0` This is only a temporary fix.